# Prevent overflow/underflow in float division

Tags: c, floating-point

I have two numbers:

```
FL_64 variable_number;
FL_64 constant_number;
```

The constant number is always the same, for example:

```
constant_number=(FL_64)0.0000176019966602325;
```

The variable number is given to me and I need to perform the division:

```
FL_64 result = variable_number/constant_number;
```

What would be the checks I need to do to **variable_number** in order to make sure the operation will not overflow / underflow before performing it?

Edit: FL_64 is just a typedef for double so FL_64 = double.

Comment: What type is `FL_64` (including size and presentation)? Is it 64-bit `double` with IEEE 754?

Comment: What specific MISRA rule (number and text) is the compiler/checker/other tool saying is violated?

Comment: @EricPostpischil actually I misslooked the polyspace report. It is actually a runtime error, and the message says: "Unproven: operation [/] on float may overflow (on MIN or MAX bounds of FLOAT64)"

Comment: I provided a test for overflow, with proof. Division by a number with magnitude less than one cannot introduce underflow (it cannot underflow unless an underflow occurred previously; see my answer), so there is no need to test for it in this case. If you need a test, I could look at it further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A Test For Overflow

Assume:

- The C implementation uses IEEE-754 arithmetic with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even.
- The magnitude of the divisor is at most 1, and the divisor is non-zero.
- The divisor is positive.

The test and the proof below are written with the above assumptions for simplicity, but the general cases are easily handled:

- If the divisor might be negative, use `fabs(divisor)` in place of `divisor` when calculating the `limit` shown below.
- If the divisor is zero, there is no need to test for overflow, as it is already known an error (divide-by-zero) occurs.
- If the magnitude exceeds 1, the division never creates a new overflow. Overflow occurs only if the dividend is already infinity (so a test would be `isinf(candidate)`). (With a divisor exceeding 1 in magnitude, the division could underflow. This answer does not discuss testing for underflow in that case.)

Note about notation: Expressions using non-code-format operators, such as `x`•`y`, represent exact mathematical expressions, without floating-point rounding. Expressions in code format, such as `x*y`, mean the computed results with floating-point rounding.

To detect overflow when dividing by `divisor`, we can use:

```
FL_64 limit = DBL_MAX * divisor;
if (-limit <= candidate && candidate <= limit)
    // Overflow will not occur.
else
    // Overflow will occur or candidate or divisor is NaN.
```

Proof:

`limit` will equal `DBL_MAX` multiplied by `divisor` and rounded to the nearest representable value. This is exactly `DBL_MAX`•`divisor`•(1+*e*) for some error *e* such that −2<sup>−53</sup> ≤ *e* ≤ 2<sup>−53</sup>, by the properties of rounding to nearest plus the fact that no representable value for `divisor` can, when multiplied by `DBL_MAX`, produce a value below the normal range. (In the subnormal range, the relative error due to rounding could be greater than 2<sup>−53</sup>. Since the product remains in the normal range, that does not occur.)

However, *e* = 2<sup>−53</sup> can occur only if the exact mathematical value of `DBL_MAX`•`divisor` falls exactly midway between two representable values, thus requiring it to have 54 significant bits (the bit that is ½ of the lowest position of the 53-bit significand of representable values is the 54<sup>th</sup> bit, counting from the leading bit). We know the significand of `DBL_MAX` is 1fffffffffffff<sub>16</sub> (53 bits). Multiplying it by odd numbers produces 1fffffffffffff<sub>16</sub> (when multiplied by 1), 5ffffffffffffd<sub>16</sub> (by 3), and 0x9ffffffffffffb<sub>16</sub> (by 5), and numbers with more significant bits when multiplied by greater odd numbers. Note that 5ffffffffffffd<sub>16</sub> has 55 significant bits. None of these has exactly 54 significant bits. When multiplied by even numbers, the product has trailing zeros, so the number of significant bits is the same as when multiplying by the odd number that results from dividing the even number by the greatest power of two that divides it. Therefore, no product of `DBL_MAX` is exactly midway between two representable values, so the error *e* is never exactly 2<sup>−53</sup>. So −2<sup>53</sup> < *e* < 2<sup>−53</sup>.

So, `limit` = `DBL_MAX`•`divisor`•(1+*e*), where *e* < 2<sup>−53</sup>. Therefore `limit`/`divisor` is `DBL_MAX`•(1+*e*). Since this result is less than ½ ULP from `DBL_MAX`, it never rounds up to infinity, so it never overflows. So dividing any `candidate` that is less than or equal to `limit` by `divisor` does not overflow.

Now we will consider candidates exceeding `limit`. As with the upper bound, *e* cannot equal −2<sup>−53</sup>, for the same reason. Then the least *e* can be is −2<sup>−53</sup> + 2<sup>−105</sup>, because the product of `DBL_MAX` and `divisor` has at most 106 significant bits, so any increase from the midpoint between two representable values must be by at least one part in 2<sup>−105</sup>. Then, if `limit < candidate`, `candidate` is at least one part in 2<sup>−52</sup> greater than `limit`, since there are 53 bits in a significand. So `DBL_MAX`•`divisor`•(1−2<sup>−53</sup>+2<sup>−105</sup>)•(1+2<sup>−52</sup>) < `candidate`. Then `candidate`/`divisor` is at least `DBL_MAX`•(1−2<sup>−53</sup>+2<sup>−105</sup>)•(1+2<sup>−52</sup>), which is `DBL_MAX`•(1+2<sup>−53</sup>+2<sup>−157</sup>). The exceeds the midpoint between `DBL_MAX` and what would be the next representable value if the exponent range were unbounded, which is the basis for the IEEE-754 rounding criterion. Therefore, it rounds up to infinity, so overflow occurs.

## Underflow

Dividing by a number with magnitude less than one of course makes a number larger in magnitude, so it never underflows to zero. However, the IEEE-754 definition of underflow is that a non-zero result is tiny (in the subnormal range), either before or after rounding (whether to use before or after is implementation-defined). It is of course possible that dividing a subnormal number by a `divisor` less than one will produce a result still in the subnormal range. However, for this to happen, underflow must have occurred previously, to get the subnormal dividend in the first place. Therefore, underflow will never be introduced by a division by a number with magnitude less than one.

If one does wish to test for this underflow, one might similarly to the test for overflow—by comparing the candidate to the minimum normal (or the greatest subnormal) multiplied by `divisor`—but I have not yet worked through the numerical properties.

Comment: Very nice:  Corner for your review: With `|divisor| <= 1.0` as in OP's case `-limit <= candidate && candidate <= limit` makes sense.  With larger `divisor`, I'd expect `-limit < candidate && candidate < limit` or something to not pass `|candidate| == INF`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, indeed, thanks. I added notes to cover the general cases.

Comment: Nice identification of other cases `divisor <= 0` too.

Comment: Im going to accept this answer as it provides a good test before actually making the division.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `FL_64` is something like a `double` you can get the maximum value which is named **DBL_MAX** from `float.h`

So you want to make sure that

```
DBL_MAX >= variable_number/constant_number
```

or equally

```
DBL_MAX * constant_number >= variable_number
```

In code that could be something like

```
if (constant_number > 0.0 && constant_number < 1.0)
{
    if (DBL_MAX * constant_number >= variable_number)
    {
        // wont overflow
    }
    else
    {
        // will overflow
    }
}
else
{
    // add code for other ranges of constant_number
}
```

However, notice that floating point calculations are imprecise so there maybe corner cases where the above code will fail.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to attempt to answer the question you asked (instead trying to answer a different "How to detect overflow or underflow that was not prevented" question that you didn't ask).

To prevent overflow and underflow for division during the design of software:

- Determine the range of the numerator and find the values with the largest and smallest absolute magnitude
- Determine the range of the divisor and find the values with the largest and smallest absolute magnitude
- Make sure that the maximum representable value of the data type (e.g. `FLT_MAX`) divided by the largest absolute magnitude of the range of divisors is larger than the largest absolute magnitude of the range of numerators.
- Make sure that the minimum representable value of the data type (e.g. `FLT_MIN`) multiplied by the smallest absolute magnitude of the range of divisors is smaller than the smallest absolute magnitude of the range of numerators.

Note that the last few steps may need to be repeated for each possible data type until you've found the "best" (smallest) data type that prevents underflow and underflow (e.g. you might check if `float` satisfies the last 2 steps and find that it doesn't, then check if `double` satisfies the last 2 steps and find that it does).

It's also possible that you find out that no data type is able to prevent overflow and underflow, and that you have to limit the range of values that could be used for numerator or divisor, or rearrange formulas (e.g. change a `(c*a)/b` into a `(c/b)*a`) or switch to a different representation ("double double", rational numbers, ...).

Also; be aware that this provides a guarantee that (for all combinations of values within your ranges) overflow and underflow will be prevented; but doesn't guarantee that the smallest data type will be chosen if there's some kind of relationship between the magnitudes of the numerators and divisors. For a simple example, if you're doing something like `b = a*a+1; result = b/a;` where the magnitude of the numerator depends on the magnitude of the divisor, then you'll never get the "largest numerator with smallest divisor" or "smallest numerator with largest divisor" cases and a smaller data type (that can't handle cases that won't exist) may be suitable.

Note that you can also do checks before each individual division. This tends to make performance worse (due to the branches/checks) while causing code duplication (e.g. providing alternative code that uses `double` for cases when `float` would've caused overflow or underflow); and can't work when the largest type supported isn't large enough (you end up with an `} else { // Now what???` problem that can't be solved in a way that ensures values that should work do work because typically the only thing you can do is treat it as an error condition).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what standard your `FL_64` adheres to, but if it's anything like [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), you'll want to watch out for

### Not a Number

There might be a special `NaN` value. In some implementation, the result of comparing it to anything is `0`, so if `(variable_number == variable_number) == 0`, then that's what's going on. There might be macros and functions to check for this depending on the implementation, such as in the [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html).

### Infinity

IEEE 754 also supports infinity (and negative infinity). This can be the result of an overflow, for instance.  If `variable_number` is infinite and you divide it by `constant_number`, the result will probably be infinite again. As with `NaN`, the implementation usually supplies macros or functions to test for this, otherwise you could try dividing the number by something and see if it got any smaller.

### Overflow

Since dividing the number by `constant_number` will make it bigger, the `variable_number` could overflow if it is already enormous. Check if it's not so big that this can happen. But depending on what your task is, the possibility of it being this large might already be excluded. The 64 bit floats in IEEE 754 go up to about 10^308. If your number overflows, it might turn into infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't know the FL_64 variable type, from the name I suppose it has a 64 bit representation, but is it signed or unsigned?

Anyway I would see a potential problem only if the type is signed, otherwise both the quotient and reminder would be re-presentable on the same quantity of bits.

In case of signed, you need to check the result sign:

```
FL_64 result = variable_number/constant_number;

if ((variable_number > 0 && constant_number > 0) || (variable_number < 0 && constant_number < 0)) {
    if (result < 0) {
        //OVER/UNDER FLOW
        printf("over/under flow");
    } else {
        //NO OVER/UNDER FLOW
        printf("no over/under flow");
    }
} else {
    if (result < 0) {
        //NO OVER/UNDER FLOW
        printf("no over/under flow");
    } else {
        //OVER/UNDER FLOW
        printf("over/under flow");
    }
}
```

Also other cases should be checked, like division by 0. But as you mentioned `constant_number` is always fixed and different from 0.

EDIT:

Ok so there could be another way to check overflow by using the `DBL_MAX` value. By having the maximum re-presentable number on a double you can multiply it by the `constant_number` and compute the maximum value for the `variable_number`. From the code snippet below, you can see that the first case does not cause overflow, while the second does (since the `variable_number` is a larger number compared to the `test`). From the console output in fact you can see that the first value `result` is higher than the second one, even if this should actually be the double of the previous one. So this case is an overflow case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

typedef double FL_64;

int main() {
    FL_64 constant_number = (FL_64)0.0000176019966602325;
    FL_64 test = DBL_MAX * constant_number;
    FL_64 variable_number = test;
    FL_64 result;

    printf("MAX double value:\n%f\n\n", DBL_MAX);

    printf("Variable Number value:\n%f\n\n", variable_number);
    printf(variable_number > test ? "Overflow case\n\n" : "No overflow\n\n");
    result = variable_number / constant_number;
    printf("Result: %f\n\n", variable_number);

    variable_number *= 2;

    printf("Variable Number value:\n%f\n\n", variable_number);
    printf(variable_number > test ? "Overflow case\n\n" : "No overflow\n\n");
    result = variable_number / constant_number;
    printf("Result:\n%f\n\n", variable_number);

    return 0;
}
```

This a specific case solution, since you have a constant value number. But this solution will not work in a general case.

Comment: +1 for mentioning division by zero. Sure, it's not applicable to this exact situation, but always something good to keep in mind when doing float math.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain, but FL_64 is same as double (it is just a typedef).

I like your approach, but the problem is you need to evaluate the result, which means you need to perform the operation.

I have a problem with MISRA telling me that the operation may overflow, so that is why I want to make all the possible checks before making the operation itself.

Comment: This answer addresses integer types, but the title says “float.”